# Making Monad type showable

Tags: haskell

I am making a maze generator and wish to visualize the maze by printing. I have a wall type and a function that generates a random maze of those walls.

```
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive as Graph
import           Data.Graph.Inductive (Gr, prettyPrint)
data WeightedWall = WeightedWall (Int, Int, Int) Orientation deriving (Eq)
weightedGrid :: MonadRandom m => Int -> Int -> Gr () (m WeightedWall)
```

However, when I call `prettyPrint(weightedGrid 10 10)`, I get this error:

```
  Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘prettyPrint’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show
                              (m0 WeightedWall))’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘m0’ should be.
```

What am I missing in my code to fix this?

Comment: What `MonadRandom` do you want `m` to be?

Comment: I'm new to Haskell and am not sure what it should be. The function injecting randomness in weightedGrid is  getRandomR from Control.Monad.Random if that helps.

Comment: Some possible values for `m` would be [`Rand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Random-Lazy.html#t:Rand) or `IO`. The compiler doesn't know which one to use unless you give a type annotation to the result of your call to `weightedGrid`.

Comment: `fmap prettyPrint (weightedGrid 10 10)` will help, assuming you figure out how to properly specify which specific monad to use to generate the random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want your pretty printer to have type:

```
prettyPrint :: WeightedWall -> String
```

Then, you will need to pluck a `WeightedWall` from your `MonadRandom` instance, pass it to `prettyPrint`, and then print the `String` in the `IO` monad.

The `getRandomR` function is a member of the `MonadRandom` typeclass, so it doesn't tell us which `MonadRandom` instance you are using.  I'm going to assume `IO` since it kills two birds with one stone (the random source and the printing).  Your `main` function could look as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    ww <- weightedGrid 10 10  -- pluck weighted wall from MonadRandom instance IO
    putStrLn $ prettyPrint ww
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
pp :: WeightedWall -> String
pp (WeightedWall (a, b, c) _) = show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " " ++ show c

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ww <- mapM Data.Graph.Inductive.edgeLabel $ labEdges (weightedGrid 10 10)
  forM_ (map pp ww) putStrLn
```